# Getting 'jquery_connections__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ is not a function' error when using jquery-connections npm package in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, connection, npm-package

How to use [jquery-connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-connections) library in Angular application and use it in every files?

I have a requirement to connect the different div elements in my Angular application using lines. I have identified that the jquery-connections npm package can do it.

But I am unable to use it in my Angular application. I have followed the below steps to use that library in my Angular application:

step 1 : Installed the library using the command `npm i jquery-connections`

step 2 : Added the jquery.connections.js file path in angular.json files scripts section as below :

#### angular.json file :

```
.
.
.
 "scripts": [ 
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-connections/jquery.connections.js"
            ],
...
```

step 3 : reran the application using ng server command.

step 4 : In my component html may look like below:

#### component.html file :

```
<div id="div1" class="border">I am one div</div>
<br /><br />

<button class="btn btn-primary">I am button</button><br /><br />

<div id="div2" class="border">I am second DIV</div>
```

step 5 : In my TypeScript file I tried to connect those two div elements according to the API document of 'jquery-connections' as below:

Link of Api documents of jquery-connections : https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections/wiki/API

#### component.ts file :

```
import * as JQConnections from 'jquery-connections';

@Component({
  selector: 'componentSelector',
  templateUrl: '..component.html',
  styleUrls: ['...scss'],
})
export class component implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    JQConnections('#div1', '#div2').connections();
  }
```

This is what I have tried so far.

### Problem :

When I the component get initialized the below erroe is displayed in the console :

```
re.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: jquery_connections__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ is not a function
```

Have I done something wrong? Or are there any alternative ways to achieve this behaviour in Angular with ease?